# javac: invalid flag error when using arguments

Tags: java, javac

Disclaimer: I am **NOT** a Java developer.

I have a shell script that passes variables into my java program.

```
#!/bin/bash
$JAVA_HOME/javac -classpath $clp myjavaapp.java "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

When I run this script I get the following error:

```
javac: invalid flag: /public/rest/api/1.0/cycles/search?versionId=-1&projectId=10005
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Where `/public/rest/api/1.0/cycles/search?versionId=-1&projectId=10005` is the value passed it at `$3`.

Here is a sample of the contents of my `myjavaapp.java` file:

```
package myjavaapp;

...

public class myjavaapp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IllegalStateException, IOException {

      ...

      String variable1 = args[0];
      String variable2 = args[1];
      String variable3 = variable2 + args[2];

      ...

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I using the arguments correctly?

Comment: Are you trying to compile your program or execute it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably the value of the `$clp` variable that is  `/public/rest/api/1.0/cycles/search?versionId=-1&projectId=10005` and that is not a valid option for `javac`.
Check its value first.

Then, the passed arguments `"$1" "$2" "$3"` makes no sense :

```
$JAVA_HOME/javac -classpath $clp myjavaapp.java "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

The `javac` command is for compiling class(es), not for running applications.
You probably mixed it with the `java` command that allows to run a executable class (application) and that accepts args.

Comment: Oh man, I feel dumb. Your last point was my issue. I just need to pass my values in at the point of running the application. Thank you! `$JAVA_HOME/javac -classpath $clp myjavaapp.java` and `$JAVA_HOME/java -classpath $clp myjavaapp.java "$1" "$2" "$3"` work.

Comment: You are welcome. With such a disclaimer, don't be to rude with yourself ;-)